# Will enabling a page-level trace in ASP.Net page recycle my application pool?

Tags: asp.net

If I add "trace=true" into my  directive on an asp.net 2.0 .aspx page, will it recycle my application pool?

I know if I enable tracing in web.config that will recycle the application pool.

The webserver is IIS 6.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but it shouldn't. Any change to a web.config file would cause an app pool reset, but a page level change shouldn't even in the directive.

Check out the section "Why does an application domain recycle?" in this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2006/08/02/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles.aspx)

Technically if it's the 15th re-compile it could cause a reset... but other than that no.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will just trigger a recompile of that page. Editing of an aspx file is not a trigger for an application restart.

Why not test it out and see?

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I just tried it out on a testing server - adding in the "trace=true" directive on the page level did NOT recycle the application pool.

Answer (score 0):

It won't.  the app pool only recycles when a dll is changed in the Bin directory or if the web.config file is changed.  If you are concerned about loosing your session info as that is what the question seems to me to be more related to then you can use the asp.net session state provider and that way your app pool can recycle as many times as it likes without you loosing your session.